# How can I do a join statement in Laravel and then query the results by 2 particular user ID's and then sum a particular column

Tags: sql, laravel, join

I have a transactions table and a sold products table. The transactions table has a buyer_id and a product_id column. The sold_products table has a seller_id column and an id column. I would like to join the tables together using transactions.product_id and sold_products.id. How can I then query the returned results based on a buyer_id and a product_id, followed by summing a quantity  column?

I have tried this already however it doesn't work

```
$quantity_bought = DB::table('transactions')->select(DB::raw('SUM(sold_products.quantity_available)'))->
                join('sold_products', 'transactions.product_id',
                '=', 'sold_products.id')->where('transactions.buyer_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('sold_products.id', $product->seller_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you only need to add a groupBy like this

```
      $quantity_bought = DB::table('transactions')
           ->select(DB::raw('SUM(sold_products.quantity_available)'))
           ->join('sold_products', 'transactions.product_id','=', 'sold_products.id')
           ->where('transactions.buyer_id', Auth::user()->id)
           ->where('sold_products.id', $product->seller_id)
           ->groupBy('transactions.buyer_id','sold_products.id')
           ->get();
```